# How does HAWQ handle different kill signals?

Tags: hawq

If I kill -QUIT the master resource manager process, it restarts and then runs normally. But if I kill -ABRT the master resource manager process, it restarts but processes on HAWQ restart. So how does HAWQ handle different kill signals?

Comment: It should be "But if I kill -ABRT the master resource manager process, it restarts but processes on HAWQ master restart".

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple processes started by postmaster
1. Resource Manager
2. master logger process
3. stats collector process
4. writer process
5. checkpoint process
6. seqserver process
7. WAL Send Server process
8. DFS Metadata Cache Process.

For the SIGNAL response, different processes have different handling.

1. master logger process is independent with other processes, other process restart will not influence it, and its restart will not influence other processes too. For SIGQUIT, it will ignore. For SIGABORT and SIGKILL, it will restart.
2. stats collector process doesn't influence other processes, but will be influenced by other process's restart. For signal SIGQUIT, SIGABORT, or SIGKILL, it will restart itself.
3. Resource Manager process, For signal SIGQUIT, it will restart itself, for signal SIGABORT and SIGKILL, will restart all other sub-processes.
4. The other 5 processes, for signal SIGQUIT, SIGABORT, or SIGKILL, will restart itself and all other sub-processes except master logger process.

Comment: How about kill -15?

Comment: kill -15 is SIGTERM.   The Resource Manager, stats collector, and WAL Send server process will restart themselves when they meet kill -15. Other processes just ignore the signal.

Answer (score 1):

HAWQ Resource Manager catches the signal SIGQUIT, and registers a function named quitResManager to handle the signal. The process will quit peaceably. But for the signal SIGABRT, the Resource manager will generate coredump according to the definition of SIGABORT.

Since the Resource manager process is forked by postmaster, the postmaster process keeps an eye on watching its subprocess, and will restart the sub-process itself if finding subprocess normally quits, but will restart all the sub-processes if finding error in subprocess.

So you can see the Resource Manager process itself is restarted after you send kill -QUIT, but see all the processes on the HAWQ master restarted after you send kill -ABORT.

Comment: Btw, HAWQ Resource Manager will do similar handling as SIGQUIT for SIGINT, SIGTERM, and SIGUSR2.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Btw, if I send a kill signal to one of processes which are forked by postmaster, which signals would cause this process restart and which signals cause postmaster process restart?

Comment: There are multiple processes started by postmaster:      1. Resource Manager; 2. master logger

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if hawq resource manager process is killed by SIGKILL, whether parent postmaster process will also exit?

Comment: I have tried this and find that only sub-processes restart and parent postmaster process run normally.

Answer (score 0):

@huan, parent postmaster will not restart itself if any sub-processes meets error. But if itself meets error, it will not restart anyone, all the sub-processes will be killed.